# Detect Image border/edge and crop - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, ocr, image-scanner

I am developing a OCR app for scan IC card and passport.

Now I want to crop the IC card by detecting the edges.

For an example:

I have tried https://github.com/mmackh/IPDFCameraViewController but its not very accurate for white card on a white background.

I am searching for something like the "Border Detector" uses BlinkID ios library
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios

Can anyone suggest me a good library for live detecting borders of a image and crop.

Comment: try using https://github.com/hartws1/IRLScanner ..it works for  me

Comment: Checkout [OPENCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) for image processing, it has many such features you require.

Comment: try this https://github.com/mukyasa/MMCamScanner it might be helpful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.